# Devenv crashes when passing params from the command line

Tags: c#, .net, devenv

I am using the following command from command line

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"  C:\testlocation\testsolution.sln /Rebuild "Debug" /project "testproject" /projectconfig "Debug" /out C:\test.sln.log
```

this command however makes devenv to crash. Nothing is being written to the test.sln.log file.
Can somebody please point out what the case might be ?

[Update 1]

Crash Image is [here](http://s16.postimage.org/3putboved/Image_2.png). If I click the view problem details this is the information that i get

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>     Application Name:         devenv.exe
>     Application Version:     10.0.30319.1
>     Application Timestamp:              4ba1fab3
>     Fault Module Name:    msenv.dll
>     Fault Module Version: 10.0.30319.1
>     Fault Module Timestamp:          4ba1fd94
>     Exception Code:             c0000005
>     Exception Offset:           0030df30
>     OS Version:      6.0.6001.2.1.0.256.1
>     Locale ID:           1033 
>   Additional information about the problem:
>     LCID:    1033
>   Read our privacy statement:
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409

[Update 2]
I found out from the solution file that this is the configuration

> ```
>   Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
>     Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
>     Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
>     Release|x64 = Release|x64
> ```

so if I am building it for Debug only (without the platform) is devenv supposed to crash like it does for me ?

thanks

Comment: Define "crash".  What exactly happens?  Error message?  BSOD?

Comment: have you tried it without the log parameter? I wonder if it's having trouble creating the log file

Comment: Tried it but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Looks like /projectconfig needs "Debug|Win32", so the name of a configuration *and* a platform, separated by a pipe character.

Answer (score 0):

Using [err.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985) appears to be a security problem:

> for hex 0xc0000005 / decimal -1073741819 :
>   STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION       ntstatus.h
>   The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at
>   "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".
>   USBD_STATUS_DEV_NOT_RESPONDING   usb.h
>   2 matches found for "c0000005"

Confirm you are running the Visual Studio command line prompt as administrator.

Comment: I am launching normal cmd window and executing devenv from there. I am not using Visual Studio Command prompt.

Comment: Hi Nav, why not? Obviously you would need to run the command from the Visual Studio command line prompt. `Start > Programs > Visual Studio 2010 > Tools > Command Line prompt.` ps the configuration info doesn't really have anything to do with the crash.

Comment: Actually its part of a build system that is employed in our company. Devenv is being launched as a "command line switch" from the command prompt and not from the Visual studio command line prompt.

Comment: Also , i think it should be the same if i call devenv (by passing the full path to the devenv) from the cmd prompt and pass proper values to it , right?

Comment: BTW ..i launched it with visual studio command prompt ( running it as administrator) and i have the same results. It still crashes.

Comment: Ok, check you can run the command on a hello world application. Check the event logs, run process monitor while the problem occurs, check to see if you get any hints as to what the root cuase may be.  If you still get a crash on a Hello World app and the logs dont give you any clues, setup windbg to capture a memory dump, then open windbg load up the symbols (pdb's) and issue a !Analyze.

Comment: Well, to be very honest, I did run it with other solutions/projects before coming here. They all compile successfully without any issues. This leaves me absolutely stumped!